# App Icon in Remote Notification alert box

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I am sending push notification an iOS app using php.

Whenever the push notification is displayed in the iPhone I want to display my App's Icon in the notification.

How this can be done ?

Comment: @Rushi .. I know that link. Can you give me the solution ?

Comment: From where are you sending the notification ?

Comment: @V-Xtreme... from a MAMP server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for something like below:

[image: Push notification]

It's default behavior of push notification in Lock screen.

You don't need to do anything to display your notification like this.

Image from [Google](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Vti&sa=X&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=np&biw=1600&bih=717&tbm=isch&tbnid=SSeStrn20KqzzM:&imgrefurl=http://thenextweb.com/apps/2012/10/29/netbot-for-app-net-gets-push-notifications-and-full-search-support/&docid=g30rJ3o74BwzfM&imgurl=http://cdn.thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/10/IMG_0942.png&w=640&h=960&ei=seHzUJTyBYPykQWZ5oFw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=4&vpy=228&dur=6539&hovh=275&hovw=183&tx=79&ty=153&sig=105717649603477773507&page=1&tbnh=134&tbnw=89&start=0&ndsp=46&ved=1t:429,r:23,s:0,i:157).

Answer (score 1):

The notifications are displayed either as banner or as alert. Your cant set any app icon on the alert and the icon on the banner is automatically taken from your app icon in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things a push notification can do:

1. Display a short text message
2. Play a brief sound
3. Set a number in a badge on the app’s icon.

I don't think you can manually set the app icon in push notification message.

Ray Wenderlich did a great tutorial on this. Try this two links:

Part 1: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Part 2: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

Comment: @rushi.... Dude I am able to send push notification I just want to add image to the alert. So don't give all these links as you answer to my questions as they tell "How to send push notification"

Comment: @Mayank "I don't think you can manually set the app icon in push notification message." Buddy, Im posting all this links just for your reference. If you get anything helpful from them.